# Can't get custom markers to work in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I've followed both the [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-markers/) at Mapbox site and [this instruction](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/822#issuecomment-62662388) on GitHub but can't get markers to show on my map:

http://codepen.io/znak/pen/waPPRj (using Mapbox style and sprites)
http://codepen.io/znak/pen/PqOEyV (using custom style and sprites)

```
var center = [51.5, -0.1];

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    center: center,
    zoom: 8,
    style: 'https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-styles/styles/mapbox-streets-v7.json'
});

// Markers
map.on('style.load', function() {
    map.addSource("markers", {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [{
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [51.48, -0.08]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "Lorem",
                    "marker-symbol": "default_marker"
                }
            }, {
                "type": "Feature",
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": [51.52, -0.12]
                },
                "properties": {
                    "title": "Ipsum",
                    "marker-symbol": "secondary_marker"
                }
            }]
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "markers",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "markers",
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "{marker-symbol}",
            "text-field": "{title}",
            "text-font": "Open Sans Semibold, Arial Unicode MS Bold",
            "text-offset": [0, 0.6],
            "text-anchor": "top"
        },
        "paint": {
            "text-size": 14
        }
    });
});
```

All styles, JSON and PNG files with markers seem to load properly.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The GeoJSON layer type of Mapbox GL JS follows the [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) specification, which requires that coordinates be in longitude, latitude order. Your examples have them reversed. [Flipping them](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvXzPg) shows the markers, which have the correct icons.

```
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-0.12, 51.52]
}
```

Comment: @tmcw: What about normal `Points` in vector tiles created from PostGIS? Can't `Points` be styled, unless added as GeoJSON??

Comment: Please open a separate question for that.

Comment: is there any chance to put text inside custom marker? check out my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035655/custom-marker-with-dialog-box